# Testing for positivity instead of equality

Tags: communication-complexity, property-testing

Alice and Bob have n-bit strings, and want to figure out if they're equal while doing little communication. The standard randomized solution is to treat the n-bit strings as polynomials of degree $n$ and then evaluate the polynomials over a few randomly chosen elements from a field of size larger than $n$. This takes $O(\log |F|)$ communication.

Suppose instead that we fix a lexicographic ordering over the strings and want instead to determine which string is "larger", which is equivalent to finding the leftmost bit where the strings differ.

> Is there a similar randomized protocol for doing this, or a known
>   lower bound ? This seems to relate to testing positivity of
>   polynomials.

p.s While lexicographic order seems like the most obvious, I'm fine with other orderings: for the purpose I'm interested in, all we need is *some* order.

Comment: I thought the standard randomized solution was to pick a random linear combination of the bits, and just send the resulting parity, which takes only $O(1)$ communication?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I think that depends on the nature of randomness - public or private. The protocol you mention uses public randomness.

Comment: @SashoNikolov: Ah, yes! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: For comparison, it is perhaps worth mentioning that the deterministic complexity is $n+1$, so the trivial protocol is optimal.  This gives a nice exponential gap between deterministic/exact and randomized solutions, showing that (at least in communication complexity), randomness really can help.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon: $\;\;$ Do you know what the "zero error" complexity is? $\:$ (See ZPP) $\hspace{.15 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer what is the communication complexity analog of ZPP you have in mind?

Comment: I don't really care whether it's "gives the correct answer with probability 1; what's the $\hspace{.2 in}$ _expected_ amount of communication?" or "gives MAYBE with probability at most 1/2". $\hspace{.7 in}$ As with ZPP, those differ by at most a factor of 2+$\epsilon$. $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer: The deterministic protocol where Alice sends her most significant unsent bits, one by one, to Bob, who responds with 0 or 1 as soon as this is determined, seems to have expected complexity something like $1+\sum_{i=1}^n i2^{-i}$, which is bounded above by 3.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon: $\:$ That's only when the parties' _inputs_ are chosen randomly, $\hspace{1 in}$ which (from my understanding) goes against the default in both "traditional" $\hspace{.8 in}$ complexity theory and communication complexity. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Indeed.  Do you have a more ZPP-like notion?

Comment: um... yeah. $\:$ How much communication is needed for an algorithm that never gives the wrong answer and, for all input pairs, gives MAYBE to that input pair with probability at most 1/2?

Comment: maybe this should become a separate question in itself ?

Comment: See separate question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17529/testing-for-equality-with-zero-error

Comment: Maybe it is worth to mention that the $k$-round communication complexity of greater than is $\Omega(n^{1/k}k^{-2})$ in particular i.e. it is linear for $k=1$, see http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0309033. It is a nice paper :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is known as Greater-Than problem in communication complexity. An algorithm with $O(\log n) $ communication complexity exists (Exercise 3.18 in Nisan-Kushilevitz book).

Edit: The algorithm is due to Nisan (page 10): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.57.6891&rep=rep1&type=pdf

It uses the approach suggested by @Sasho Nikolov below --- running a binary search using equality tests with constant error to do the comparisons. This can be done with $O(\log n)$ queries using the "noisy binary search algorithm" by Feige, Peleg, Raghavan and Upfal: http://cs.brown.edu/~eli/papers/SICOMP23FRPU.pdf

To get a (non-explicit) private randomness protocol one can apply the result of Newman: http://pdf.aminer.org/000/933/113/private_vs_common_random_bits_in_communication_complexity.pdf

Comment: One easy solution with polylog communication is to use equality to do a binary search for the first bit where the strings differ. The $\log n$ solution is with public randomness: again use equality  as an oracle, but perform each equality test with constant probability of error so that each equality call uses $O(1)$ bits; now simple binary search does not suffice, you need "noisy binary search", but there are ways to do this with log complexity

Comment: Not sure what "noisy binary search" is, but you can do $O(\log n \log \log n)$ in the public randomness model by doing binary search using equality tests with error probability $O(1 / \log n)$, which requires $O(\log \log n)$ communication per test, and you get constant error probability overall by a union bound.

Comment: @SashoNikolov Ok, I guess something like this can be used as a "noisy binary search", which tolerates a constant fraction of errors so that we can use constant error probability in the equality tests: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=167129

Comment: true. I meant binary search where each comparison can give the wrong result with small constant probability. I think this paper gives the needed result, for example: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=100230

Comment: Moved the discussion into the answer.

Answer (score 7):

See [The communication complexity of addition](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/papers/ccsum.pdf).

As Grigory mentioned, there is a protocol with communication $O(\log n)$.  This is due to Nisan and Safra.  Their protocol either uses public randomness or is not explicit.  The above paper gives one that uses private randomness and is explicit (via a relatively standard use of pseudorandom generators); it also discusses matching lower bounds in the public-randomness model.