# Testing for equality with zero error

Tags: communication-complexity

This question comes from what I asked in a comment [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17482/testing-for-positivity-instead-of-equality#comment45474_17482), although I realized that
I don't actually care about which input is less than the other, if they're different.

Alice and Bob have n-bit strings, and want to figure out if they're equal
while doing little communication. $\:$ They can use a randomized solution,
but there must be zero chance of getting the wrong answer.

Parametrized by $n$, how much communication is needed to for a protocol that:

- outputs one of {NO,MAYBE,YES}
- for all input pairs, the probability of the protocol outputting MAYBE on that pair is at most 1/2
- the protocol never outputs YES on unequal inputs, and never outputs NO on equal inputs
  ?

Since this falls between the deterministic and the standard randomized cases,
the bounds for those are upper and lower bounds, respectively, for this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $D$ be the distribution on inputs that w.p. $p = 1/(1+\epsilon)$ picks $(x,x)$ for random $x$, and w.p. $1-p$ picks $(x,y)$ for random $x \neq y$. An appropriate choice of random coins leads to a deterministic protocol that never makes mistakes and outputs MAYBE w.p. at most $1/2$ with respect to $D$. In particular, it must answer YES on at least $1-(1/2)/p = 1/2 - \epsilon/2$ of the nodes $(x,x)$.

Suppose that the protocol uses $C$ bits of communications. It therefore has at most $2^C$ leaves. Each leaf is a monochromatic combinatorial rectangle, and so each of the at least $(1-\epsilon) 2^{n-1}$ YES answers must end up in a different leaf. We conclude that $C \geq n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that $C <= n-1$ seems a little high.  If we are looking at bounds, lets assume that for a given communication $C$ the cost of the communication is at most $C=\gamma n + \Delta$, where $\gamma$ and $\Delta$ are fixed (a simple value for $\gamma$ would be 1).  If $\Delta$ is the answer {YES,NO,MAYBE} then as $n$ grows the cost of $C \equiv n$.  But we can also assume that $1/2$ of the time we can just answer MAYBE, which has a cost of just $\Delta$.

If on the first communication we use the normal protocol, it will cost $n$.

On the second communication we can use the MAYBE answer, this cost $\Delta$.

Over time we alternate between the two and thus we have a cost of $(n + \Delta)/2$ which approches $n/2$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

There are more complex solutions that can use hashes to reduce the communication required for inputs that don't match that can be much lower than $n/2$, depending on the likelihood that the inputs match.

Comment: I don't understand: the question does not mention C?

Comment: I was referring to the previous answer.